# Gson Library to write a file in Directory

Tags: java, json, streaming, gson

I need help to understand Jsonwriter option of Gson library. Basically, I could read the file from that location. Then I modified the data after converting it to Java List. I could send the modified json to ajax response and everything work fine. Now I want to save this modified json in the specified file too. One thing I want to make sure that File was cleared and updated with new json value.

```
//Read File done
//converted to list
//List modified
//converting to Json 

String json = new Gson().toJson(myData);
System.out.println(json);

// Sent to ajax response and worked fine
// Now update file with new json...

//JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(new FileWriter(ctx.getRealPath("file.text")));


    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File(ctx.getRealPath("file.txt")));
    writer.write(json);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
```

Thank you in advance !

Alternative code------

```
FileWriter fw = null;
                try {
                    fw = new FileWriter(new File(ctx.getRealPath("file.txt")));
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                    bw.write(json);
                    bw.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (fw != null) {
                            fw.close();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You have the string to write, you can use regular IO to write string into a file. `JsonWriter` kind of overkill here.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I am trying with FileWriter. But its not working. Could please look at this modified question ? Basically file in webcontent folder remains as it was before.

Comment: are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: not really, thats the problem. Is it because, its an web application ? I tried in other way. Please see the newly added code

Comment: `e.printStackTrace()` will print to the server console. Try look at `catalina.out` if you are using tomcat. There would be different default console log locations for different servers. Also try to catch the `Exception` for testing instead of `IOException`.